# While loops in Python 3 and True/False conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

So, I'm learning Python through a series of videos on YT and this time, while loops are being covered. The exemple code is thus:

```
given_list2=[5,4,4,3,1,-2,-3,-5]
total3=0
i=0
while True:
    total3+=given_list2[i]
    i+=1
    if given_list2[i]<=0:
        break
print(total3)
```

Running the script, I get 17 as a result. Then, experimenting with the code, I exchanged `True` for `False` as thus:

```
given_list2=[5,4,4,3,1,-2,-3,-5]
total3=0
i=0
while False:
    total3+=given_list2[i]
    i+=1
    if given_list2[i]<=0:
        break
print(total3)
```

And it gives me 0 as a result. I'm trying to understand why that's the case. Like, what is it being considered `True` that keeps running the code, and what is being considered `False` that it fails to even initialize the code?

Comment: `True` and `False` are getting evaluated as themselves. `while False:` never enters the loop... `while True` never terminates unless you break or return from inside the loop (return only in a function, fo course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the answer is `0` is because `while False` means that the body of the loop is not going to be executed even a single time, and since `total3` is only incremented in the body loop, its value is going to stay the same as before the loop, which is `0` because of `total3=0` line above it.

In order for the loop body to execute the value of the expression after `while` should be [truthy](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html). The most common truthy value is `True`.

Answer (score -1):

A while loop evaluates a condition and executes the code in its block when the condition evaluates to `True`, otherwise it exits the loop. The condition `True` causes the loop to continue infinitely since it can only ever evaluate to True, while `False` causes the loop to immediately exit without running the code in its block.

I know this is only an example of how to use a while loop, however, had this been an actual use case you'd want to use a for loop instead.

```
given_list2 = [5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5]
total3 = 0

for n in given_list2:
    if n > 0:
        total3 += n
    else:
        break

print(total3)
```

or even

```
total3 = sum(n for n in given_list2 if n > 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

True and False are boolean literal values. That is, their values are known and set by the language. Imagine if you had something like:

```
while 1 < 2:
```

The "1" and the "2" are integer literal values. The expression is never changing, the results will always be the same. In this case, the result is a boolean value equal to `True`.

So a while loop that has "True" or any unchanging true expression, like `1 < 2`, as the condition, is going to want to run "forever" because it will never fail that test. The only way to stop such a loop is to generate a keyboard exception (usually by pressing "Ctrl-C"), or to have an uncaught exception occur inside the code somewhere, or to have some piece of code execute a `break` statement.

In your example, you are adding up the numbers in the `given_list2` and stop (by executing a `break`) when you encounter a negative number. So the positive numbers are summed, which is 17.

Similarly, a `while` loop that has "False" or any unchanging false expression as the condition is *never* going to run, because the very first test of `while 1 > 2` will fail and the loop will abort. This results in none of the inside code being executed.

In your example, you start with `total3 = 0` and never run any code, so it stays 0.

Comment: Please don't encourage low-quality questions by answering them -- if you see something that has duplicates, shows little research effort, or both, just link to the duplicate.